# Logstash wont start on windows

Tags: logstash

I'm trying to use logstash on windows 10.
So far I am stuck on this matter:

```
$ bin/logstash -f conf.conf 
NoMethodError: undefined method `each_pair' for "C:/Sources/logstash-5.2.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0":String
Did you mean?  each_char
  paths= at C:/jruby-9.1.7.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems.rb:388
  setup! at C:/Sources/logstash-5.2.1/lib/bootstrap/bundler.rb:49
  <main> at C:/Sources/logstash-5.2.1/lib/bootstrap/environment.rb:67
```

It seems that a string is passed instead of an array.
I cant find any clue on this problem.
Could anyone be kind enough to help me ?

Théo

Comment: Did you found the solution?

Comment: nop, i gave up.

Comment: It didn't worked for me either until I run this in git bash. Then everything was okay.

Answer (score 0):

This could be:

1. conflict between the Jruby Version installed on your machine and the Jruby version embed on logstash. Remove the JRUBY_BIN env var and start your logstash.
2. JAVA_HOME not configured